# List of a module's submodules

Tags: ruby

I'm creating an API for versioning Rails apps using modules as follows:

```
Module Api
  Module V1
   Controller goes here
  end
end

Module Api
  Module V2
    Controller goes here
  end
end
```

I wish to know the latest available version. I thought I could get it by looking at `Api.constants`, but this doesn't seem to be the case since I get an empty array as shown below:

```
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.12)
irb(main):001:0> Api
=> Api
irb(main):002:0> Api.constants
=> []
```

However, if I first call `Api::V1` directly, it seems to work:

```
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.12)
irb(main):001:0> Api
=> Api
irb(main):002:0> Api.constants
=> []
irb(main):003:0> Api::V1
=> Api::V1
irb(main):004:0> Api.constants
=> [:V1]
```

Is there a way to get all the submodules without accessing them in advance?

Comment: Your code is invalid.

Comment: @sawa: you mean Pascal-cased "Module"?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Yes.

Comment: if you need to cheat things, and aren't using Rails eager loading, consider just placing the name of the mode after the closing end... Module Api; Module V2; blah...; end; V2; end;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is auto-loading at work. `Api::V1` isn't loaded until it's referenced. That's why you get empty array in the first case.

You can tune your app to eagerly load classes. See more info here: [Configuring Rails](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html).